# How to make alert on click of button

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, alert, antd

Is there a way to make Alert on click not using the alert method but Alert tag. Currently I tried using usestate but didn’t work

Comment: Hello, I've tried to answer but it would be useful to see some code examples so that members can see what (and how) you've tried to tackle the issue. When you say you have tried something it could be a small error in your implementation that is making it fail. Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to know what your problem is without seeing code but this is the general approach to show tag based components. Don't forget to revert the state value on dismissal.

```
const [showAlert, setShowAlert ] = useState(false);

return (
 <>
 {showAlert ?
  <Alert {...otherPropsHere} />
 : <View/> }
 <Button title="Press Me" onPress={() => {setShowAlert(true)} />
 </>
)
```

If the tag has a 'visible' prop then it would be more like this

```
const [showAlert, setShowAlert ] = useState(false);

return (
 <>
 <Alert visible={showAlert} {...otherPropsHere} />
 <Button title="Press Me" onPress={() => {setShowAlert(true)} />
 </>
)
```

If you need multiple alerts you could:

```
const [showAlertOne, setShowAlertOne ] = useState(false);

return (
 <>
 {showAlertOne ?
  <Alert {...otherPropsHere} />
 : <View/> }
{showAlertTwo ?
  <Alert {...otherPropsHere} />
 : <View/> }
 <Button title="Show Alert One" onPress={() => {setShowAlertOne(true)} />
<Button title="Show Alert Two" onPress={() => {setShowAlertTwo(true)} />
 </>
)
```

This isn’t the best way to do it but I think this should clear up the concept of what you are trying to do. A better way - if the alerts don’t show at the same time - is to have a single state object in which you store which alert you want to show. These could be an ENUM too to add a little safety.

This is the (partially) typed example with an enum and a wrapped component.

```
const myApp = () => {

  enum AlertType = { One, Two, Three }
  const [visibleAlert, setVisibleAlert ] = useState<AlertType | null>(null);

  const VisibleAlert = (alertType:AlertType) => {
    switch (visibleAlert) {
      case AlertType.One:
        return <Alert {otherPropsHere} />
      break;
      case AlertType.One:
        return <Alert {otherPropsHere} />
      break;
      default:
        return <View/>
      break;
    }
  }>

  return (
   <>
     <VisibleAlert alertType={visibleAlert} />
     <Button title="Show Alert One" onPress={() => {setVisibleAlert(AlertType.One)} />
     <Button title="Show Alert Two" onPress={() => {setVisibleAlert(AlertType.Two)} />
   </>
  )
}
```

Wrapping the modal in a component with its own state might be a good approach but let’s see what your issue is for sure first.

Comment: Thank you for your update. <Alert> doesn’t have visible option . I was try with the first solution I’m getting I’m getting View cannot be used as JSX component

Comment: Could you share some code and maybe add a link to the library that you are using?

Comment: render: () =>
   <>
     <Button
          onclick={(e) => { e.stopPropagation();}}>copy</Button> {showalert ? Then comes the alert code. I’m getting the alert but if I click at one button all alert from other buttons pop-up. I need alert for just that button to pop

Comment: If you modify your original question to include the code. You can format it to make it easier for others to read and give assistance :) (4 spaces at the start of a line for code snippets)

Comment: From what I can see your alert is working but you have an issue with the others. So could you share the code for one of the others too please. They might just be sharing the same state.